# How to add a tomcat server LifeCycleListener in Spring boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, listener

We are trying to add a our own listener in Spring boot application like :

`<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"`>

How do we add this in a Spring boot application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by add this config class to your project:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Created by jacks808@163.com on 16/10/28.
 */
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addContextLifecycleListeners(null);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And more detail here:[spring boot document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-configurableembeddedservletcontainerfactory-directly)

Comment: We tried this solution by simply initializing the listener and passes into addContextLifecycleListeners, but it is not working. We have to explicitly invoke the lifecycleEvent(..) with all required arguments to make it work. Because in server.xml we just add the listener entry, do you have any idea on initializing the listener? Do we have any solution to this issue?

Comment: Did you add the impl class of a Listener by using this line: factory.addContextLifecycleListeners("Some Impl Class of Listener");

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of spring boot the implementation has changed.

```
@Component
public class MyTomcatWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        // customize the factory here
    }
}
```

[The spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-webserver)